# How To Run Two For Loop At Once in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

**I'm just a newbie in kotlin and started to solve problems through it. but one thing is confusing me how to do that!**

```
for(int i = 0, j = arr.length - 1; i < arr.length - 1; i++, j--){
      //do something      
}
```

**How to run two for loop at once in kotlin, like the above snippet code that is being done with java.**

Comment: Yes i was looking for that and didnt know its called multivariable for loop!

thanks @iCediCe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this

```
for ( (i, j) in (0..6).zip(6 downTo 0)){
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use single loop with inverted index

```
var j = 0
for(i in arr.indices){
    j = arr.lastIndex - i
    //i will go from 0 to lastindex
    //j will go from lastindex to 0
}
```

or using `zip`

```
for ((i, j) in arr.indices.zip(arr.indices.reversed())){
    //i will go from 0 to lastindex
    //j will go from lastindex to 0  
}
```